# Не меняются стили одного блока при наведении на другой

Tags: css, css3

Есть вот такой HTML

```css
.block__img {
  width: 360px;
  height: 202.5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.img__overlay {
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  transform: scaleY(0.2);
}

.img__container {
  width: 360px;
  height: auto;
}

.img__container:hover+.img__overlay {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<div class="block__img">
  <div class="img__overlay"></div>
  <!-------- lib/img/block__img3.jpg -------->
  <img src="//picsum.photos/200/300" alt="block__img_3" class="img__container">
</div>
```

Comment: Поменяйте местами блоки, у вас `img__container` идет после `img__overlay`

Comment: в css можно выбрать только следующий элемент

Comment: E_K, Спасибо, помогло! :)